# Joomla Registration MySQL Error

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla3.1, joomla3.2

Anytime someone goes to register (We use RSForms for this) we get this error

```
Warning

Registration failed: SQL=INSERT INTO (,,,,,,,,,,,,,,) VALUES (105,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0)
```

Then I turned error reporting to developer and got these when I tried to sign up.

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant DS - assumed 'DS' in /home/content/03/7103303/html/plugins/system/jcktypography/jcktypography.php on line 15

Notice: Use of undefined constant DS - assumed 'DS' in /home/content/03/7103303/html/plugins/system/jcktypography/jcktypography.php on line 15

Strict Standards: Non-static method JApplicationSite::getMenu() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/content/03/7103303/html/templates/hot_designnow/index.php on line 40

Strict Standards: Non-static method JApplicationCms::getMenu() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /home/content/03/7103303/html/libraries/cms/application/site.php on line 250

Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in /home/content/03/7103303/html/templates/hot_designnow/index.php on line 40
```

Also when turning on debug system and language I get these in red(We are using the default register now)

```
**Parsing errors in language files**
JROOT/administrator/language/en-GB/en-GB.com_rsform.ini : error(s) in line(s) 546
```

also when looking at Extention Manager -> Manage there is a new plugin/module
Code:
COM_INSTALLER_TYPE_

I hope this helps, Thank you for taking the time to try to help

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you have 3 different problems here:

Your first error message

```
Warning

Registration failed: SQL=INSERT INTO (,,,,,,,,,,,,,,) VALUES (105,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0)
```

Indicates that you are using a custom sql script in rsforms, which is somehow broken. Maybe you have upgraded from 1.5 and this custom sql (and possibly related php) needs to be rewritten?

Your second problem:

The "Notice lines indicate you have a plugin, which is not full Joomla 3.0 compatible, I would deinstall and get an upgraded version if possible.

The "Strict standards" lines are probably Joomla code not up to sratch with strict standards, but also your template has not been upgraded to adhere to these

Your third problem:

"**Parsing errors** indicated that either a language file of RSForm is missing or has not been properly upgraded. I would reinstall/upgrade RsForm.

In regards to the main angle of your question, you need to look at the custom RSForm SQL script and post that here.

Comment: Just a little addition to the second problem. If you feel uncomfortable delving into the plugin code to prevent this `DS` error, you can use this plugin: http://digitaldisseny.com/en/joomla-extensions/solve-undefined-ds-constant-joomla-3-error